# are the adjacency matrix and degree matrix right?

Tags: matrix-equations

I was wondering, is this a good (I mean by good if it follows all adjacency matrix rules) adjacency matrix ? there is 6 different nodes (A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3) :
[the Adjacency matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLZ8I.png)

And is this its degree matrix (probably its outdegree matrix): [Degree matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaAqR.png)

Comment: The Adj. matrix does not look good because you must have the same nodes in both columns and rows. You should have a row and a column for each node. This is not the case in your table. You have 3 rows of As but no corresonding columns for As. The same problem is in the case of Bs. See an example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix

Comment: @NoChance If i have in the rows and cols same nodes but not in the same order, will it be considered Adj. matrix for example : in cols : A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 and in rows : B1 B2 B3 A1 A2 A3

Comment: If you wish to just represent the fact about the connection of nodes, then like any matrix the order of rows and columns should not make a difference. However, I can't say this is true if you want to use special properties that an adjacency matrix posses, for example to find paths of length k.

Comment: @NoChance I wanna use it to get to Laplacian matrix

Comment: I am not sure if this works or not. However, it is hard to understand why you don't want to have the same sequence in rows and columns. So, you could have rows: A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3 and you could have the same order in columns as A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3. That is it.